# How do I reference unknown columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product database which includes many different product-type tables. [ I didn't design this ]. The tables look like this:

1. audio_accessories
2. audio_systems

etc. The first 12 columns in every table contain the same data:

[image: Table 1]

all the way down to Packaging.  But after that, the columns are specific to that particular product, as in this example:

[image: Table 2]

So my question is, on the product detail page, how would I reference the columns #13 and on?

I will be displaying the data in a table, so I would need to get the column name, and it's value to put in the table - all without knowing how many rows??

Can anyone help me get by this stumbling block? Thank you for looking

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are asking by "*how would I reference the columns #13 and on?*" What exactly do you mean by this - when you are doing the SQL query? In the results of the query? When you are creating the HTLM table?

Comment: I'm thinking a union query might be helpful here, maybe? Can you append the structure of both tables to the question? (no data needed, I can add dummy data)

Comment: Ok, I have been given a database of products. Each type of product is in its own table. So I designed a Master page, which lists each category's products.  When the user clicks a product, that product will DEFINITELY contain the first 12 fields above, so I can write a query getting those fields. But I then need to get the rest of the fields. These fields are simply product attributes or options. Columns 12-x will be different for each product table. So in my page, I need to be able to display those column names and values. But unless I hard code this ( over 200 tables ) I am stumped.

Comment: *So my question is, on the product detail page, how would I reference the columns #13 and on?* Simply select all columns using `SELECT * FROM ...`. Then on the PHP side analyze returned rowset metadata, get columns count and their names, and form proper grid columns amount and names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are SQL statements for every database type which give you the column names of a table. As an example "SHOW COLUMNS FROM TABLE" for MySQL/MariaDB.

As mentioned in the comment, you can also do a SELECT * FROM tablename and receive the column names. This only works if the table already contains data.